# Bootstrap: Button too high

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `legend` containing a button that I `pull-right`. Unfortunately, the button is too high. Please see a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zF5ny/).

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row pane" id="statistics-pane" style="">
        <legend>Network<span class="btn btn-mini pull-right">Test</span>
        </legend>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would separate the pull-right class from your button, and wrap in a div, like

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row pane" id="statistics-pane" style=""> 
        <legend>Network
            <div class="pull-right">
                <span class="btn btn-mini">Test</span>
            </div>
        </legend>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Some validators will scoff at block elements like `<div>` being nested within a `<legend>` element. Substituting `<span>` as the wrapper in this situation keeps the layout correct and validators happy. +1 regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe give it a top-margin to push it down a little?

```
legend .btn {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```